# How to subset character string for each list in R?

Tags: r

How to subset character string for each list in R?

Here is dummy dataset

```
mylist <- list(c("atgtgt"), c("cgcgatat"), c("cgccccc"))
mylist
# [[1]]
# [1] "atgtgt"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "cgcgatat"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "cgccccc"
```

And I would like that subset first 3 characters from each lists.
Expected Output is:

```
# [[1]]
# [1] "atg"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "cgc"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "cgc"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `substr`.  No packages are used.

```
lapply(mylist, substr, 1, 3)
## [[1]]
## [1] "atg"
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "cgc"
##
## [[3]]
## [1] "cgc"
```

Note that we could use a character vector instead of a list in which case it is even easier.

```
myvec <- unlist(mylist)
substr(myvec, 1, 3)
## [1] "atg" "cgc" "cgc"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lapply` and `str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)
lapply(mylist, function(x) str_extract(x, ".{3}"))
[[1]]
[1] "atg"

[[2]]
[1] "cgc"

[[3]]
[1] "cgc"
```

A pure `base R`solution:

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) sub("(.{3}).*", "\\1", x))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do it in base R with applying `substring()` to all elements of `mylist`

```
lapply(mylist, function(x) substring(x, 1, 3))
```

A tidyverse approach:

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

mylist_sub <- map(mylist, ~ str_sub(.x, start = 1, end = 3))
```

```
[[1]]
[1] "atg"

[[2]]
[1] "cgc"

[[3]]
[1] "cgc"
```